# Is there any possibility to change google map key dynamically in android

Tags: android, google-maps, key, api-key

In case of multiple clients, need to assign different google map api key to each. so for this i made separate build for each client.
Is there possibility to change the google map api key dynamically through code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use productFlavors you can change a resValue depending on your needs

```
android {
    ...

    productFlavors {
        cli1 {
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "CLI1_API_KEY"
         }

        cli2 {
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "CLI2_API_KEY"
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thanks, but in ios they have gmsservice.providekey("") through this change api key dynamically likewise we have anything